# Django : TokenAuthentication, setting permissions on endpoints

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework to build my API and I am quite new to it.

I set up a TokenAuthentication method, and I am now trying to filter the result of my queryset depending on this token.

Basically, I have a GET endpoint (let's say "/wallet"), and I want the /wallet endpoint to give the wallet of the specific user sending the query.

My approach was to redefine the get_queryset method in my ViewSet but I can't figure out how to get the token, and how to filter the results.

Also, anynomous users shouldn't be allowed to access that endpoint.

Here is my ViewSet, I think I need some customisation here :

```
class WalletViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows wallets to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Wallet.objects.filter()
    serializer_class = WalletSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

> My approach was to redefine the get_queryset method in my ViewSet but I can't figure out how to get the token, and how to filter the results.

Django REST framework `TokenAuthentication` is linked to the user. Therefore I would advice that you filter against the user which should be available in the view through `self.request.user`

> Also, anynomous users shouldn't be allowed to access that endpoint.

Check the permission section of the documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

To allow only authenticated users to access your viewset just do

```
class WalletViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Wallet.objects.filter()
    serializer_class = WalletSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

To get the specific user wallet you could get the user from `request` and than get it's wallet with a simple model query. The end result beig:

```
class WalletViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows wallets to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Wallet.objects.filter()
    serializer_class = WalletSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk, format=None):
        wallet = Wallet.objects.get(user=request.user)
        Response(WalletSerializer(wallet))
```